# xampp server error in Apache

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I've installed xampp server but when I click on mysql admin button it shows me an error:

[image: Error img]

and also I changed Apache port 80 to another number but Apache doesn't start and it shows me like this:

> Attempting to start Apache service... 6:26:01 PM  [Apache]    Status
>   change detected: running 6:26:05 PM  [Apache]     Status change detected:
>   stopped 6:26:05 PM  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
>   6:26:05 PM  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing
>   dependencies,  6:26:05 PM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or
>   a shutdown by another method. 6:26:05 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs
>   button to view error logs and check 6:26:05 PM  [Apache]  the Windows
>   Event Viewer for more clues 6:26:05 PM  [Apache]  If you need more
>   help, copy and post this 6:26:05 PM  [Apache]     entire log window on
>   the forums

Comment: Please include the error message as text in your post. If the image gets deleted, the original problem can no longer be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

You have something else on your machine using port 80, the same one Apache is trying to use. You have two choices:

1. Stop the other service using port 80.
2. Give Apache a different port number (like 8080) in the XAMPP application.

Comment: i also changed port 80 to another number in xampp-apache-conf-httpd file ... but it also not works

Comment: and when i click on netstat then port 80 use system

Comment: When you click on Apache on the XAMPP Control Panel what ports does it attempt to run?

Comment: it run on 443,55307 and after little time it automatically stop see this image .. link  http://oi60.tinypic.com/282jofl.jpg

Comment: Is anything else running on 443?

Comment: there is no else running on 443

Comment: I fear without more information it will be hard for us to determine what is going on. Have you considered uninstalling / reinstalling XAMPP? Or you could output the log, as suggested, and post it on XAMPP's forum for more insight.

Comment: yes i also reinstall 2 more times but problem occur same

Answer (score 0):

As you can see

```
6:26:05 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
```

Apache is not running, so the error you see on the screen is not related to mysql, but to Apache. Go into the configuration panel of xampp and change ports, some software like Skype use 433 port (web ssl), so then Apache couldn't start.

You can change the port with, for example, 8080.

Then, go to http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin

And you're done.

Comment: i also changed apache port with another number

Comment: the image which i posted is related to mysql when i press mysql admin button then it shows me error

Comment: You said on the above answer's comments that you edited httpd conf file, you have not to edit that file, you have to clicng on the "Config" button on the top right of the xampp window (above the netstat button), then click on  "Service and port settings" button". There you can easily change ports, and only those changes will be saved and used by xampp.

Comment: i also done this ... and i changed port 80 to 8080 but when i click on start button of apach then after some time it stop and doesnot work